# Comparison between two equations with SameQ - Wrong result

Tags: expression-test

I compared two equations by using SameQ as in the below example:

```
In[21]:= SameQ[y == (1 - x)/(x + 1), (y + 1) (x + 1) == 2]

Out[21]= False
```

The result should be True, instead it is False. Why and how can I get the right result?

SameQ works only sometimes:

```
In[11]:= SameQ[y == (1 + 1) x, y == 2 x]

Out[11]= True
```

Comment: If you evaluate `{y == (1 + 1) x, y == 2 x}`, you see that both elements of the list are manifestly the same. With `{y == (1 - x)/(x + 1), (y + 1) (x + 1) == 2}`, they are not.

Comment: Hello @J.M. `SameQ` should work also if I have two "complex" expressions. In the worst case I expect a message "Not possible to solve" instead of `False` when actually it is `True`.

Comment: You misunderstand the intent of `SameQ[]`. It is only intended to return `True` if all its arguments are *identical* after being evaluated. `y == (1 - x)/(x + 1)` is *not* identical with `(y + 1) (x + 1) == 2` unless you algebraically manipulate one form into the other.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for the explanation @J.M. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Do not forget that the first equation is only valid at `x!=-1`, while the second equation has no such a limitation. Therefore, these two equations are not equal to one another. Typically, Mathematica accounts for such differencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you could solve for `y` from both, and see if you get same solution

```
ClearAll[x,y];
eq1 = y == (1 - x)/(x + 1);
eq2 = (y + 1) (x + 1) == 2;
SameQ[Solve[eq1, y], Solve[eq2, y]]

(*True*)
```

Comment: Hello @Nasser thank you very much for your solution