Testing whether two expressions are mathematically equivalent
I have two mathematically equivalent expressions.  But I can't find the code to test whether they are.
I tried this
SameQ[20 + 10 t/(t + 2), 30 - 20/(t + 2)]

The output is "False".  Am I missing something?

SameQ is not the right way for this. You could try Simplify[e1 - e2] or FullSimplify and check if the result is zero or not.

Or Apart[20 + 10 t/(t + 2)] == Apart[30 - 20/(t + 2)]

SameQ considers only literal correspondence. That is why you are not getting the expected answer. Simplify[Equal[20 + 10 t/(t + 2), 30 - 20/(t + 2)]] can be used instead.

SameQ[Q&A] -> False :) —— https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238078/comparison-between-two-equations-with-sameq-wrong-result

Other similar Qs: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95426/can-mathematica-point-out-why-it-thinks-two-symbolic-expressions-are-different, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98889/difficulty-understanding-difference-between-and, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115303/testing-equivalence-of-analytical-expressions-like-x2-x-xx-1
